# jQuery function closest is returning the value of 1st row only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

The jQuery closest function I am working on is only returning the first value of the record. Please check the code below.

```
<?php
$myLat = $f['mem_latitude'];
$myLng = $f['mem_longitude'];
$mySex = $f['mem_sex'];
$myPref = explode(',', $f['mem_preference']);

$users = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE mem_id != :mem AND mem_sex != :sex ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50");
$users-> bindValue(':mem', $sessionUser);
$users-> bindValue(':sex', $mySex);
$users-> execute();

$count = 0;
while($a = $users->fetch()) {
  $userLat = $a['mem_latitude'];
  $userLng = $a['mem_longitude'];
  $userAge = getAge($a['mem_dob']);
  $userSex = $a['mem_sex'];
  $userPref = explode(',', $a['mem_preference']);
  $distance = round(distance($myLat, $myLng, $userLat, $userLng, "K"));
  $distData = round(distance($myLat, $myLng, $userLat, $userLng, "K"))." kms away";
  $geo = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/extras/location.gp?lat=$userLat&lon=$userLng&format=php"));

  if($distance < 1500) {
    if((in_array($mySex, $userPref)) && (in_array($userSex, $myPref))) {
            $count++;
?>
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-image"><img src="images/Adventure_and_Outdoor.png" width="100%" height="100%" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <div class="popular-destinations-text">
          <span class="name"><?php echo $a['mem_fname']; ?></span> <br/>
          <small><?php echo "".$userAge." ".ucfirst($a['mem_sex'])." &middot; ".$distData.""; ?></small> <br/>
          <small><?php echo "".$geo['geoplugin_place'].", ".$geo['geoplugin_region'].", ".$geo['geoplugin_countryCode'].""; ?></small>
                <!-- <small>Siliguri, West Bengal, IN</small> -->
        </div>
        <div class="popular-destinations-images">
          <div class="circle"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/jmEYL7/adventure_1.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /></div>
          <div class="circle"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/nsCynn/adventure_2.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /></div>
          <div class="circle"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/hmsL07/adventure_3.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /></div>
        </div>
        </div>
            <form class="cardform">
                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $a['mem_id']; ?>" class="hidden">
            </form>
  </div>
<?php } } } ?>

<script>
//Swipe active card to left.
function onSwipeLeft() {
    var hidid = $(".cardform").closest('form').find('.hidden').val();
    // console.log(hidid);
    alert(hidid);
    removeNoTransition();
    transformUi(-1000, 0, 0, currentElementObj);
    if(useOverlays){
        transformUi(-1000, 0, 0, leftObj); // Move leftOverlay
        transformUi(-1000, 0, 0, topObj); // Move topOverlay
        resetOverlayLeft();
    }
    currentPosition = currentPosition + 1;
    updateUi();
    currentElement();
    changeBackground();
    changeStages();
    setActiveHidden();
};
</script>
```

Here, `alert(hidid)` returns only the first row's value. I checked again and again but to me everything seems right. However, its not obviously. Please help me correct the issue.

Library

```
// JavaScript Document
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    function stackedCards () {
        var stackedOptions = 'Top'; //Change stacked cards view from 'Bottom', 'Top' or 'None'.
        var rotate = true; //Activate the elements' rotation for each move on stacked cards.
        var items = 3; //Number of visible elements when the stacked options are bottom or top.
        var elementsMargin = 10; //Define the distance of each element when the stacked options are bottom or top.
        var useOverlays = true; //Enable or disable the overlays for swipe elements.
        var maxElements; //Total of stacked cards on DOM.
        var currentPosition = 0; //Keep the position of active stacked card.
        var velocity = 0; //Minimum velocity allowed to trigger a swipe.
        var topObj; //Keep the swipe top properties.
        var rightObj; //Keep the swipe right properties.
        var leftObj; //Keep the swipe left properties.
        var listElNodesObj; //Keep the list of nodes from stacked cards.
        var listElNodesWidth; //Keep the stacked cards width.
        var currentElementObj; //Keep the stacked card element to swipe.
        var stackedCardsObj;
        var isFirstTime = true;
        var elementHeight;
        var obj;
        var elTrans;
        var refreshObj = document.getElementById("cards-refresh");
        var rotateTxt =  document.getElementById("rotate");

        obj = document.getElementById('stacked-cards-block');
        stackedCardsObj = obj.querySelector('.stackedcards-container');
        listElNodesObj = stackedCardsObj.children;

        topObj = obj.querySelector('.stackedcards-overlay.top');
        rightObj = obj.querySelector('.stackedcards-overlay.right');
        leftObj = obj.querySelector('.stackedcards-overlay.left');
        // refreshObj = obj.querySelector('.cards-refresh');

        countElements();
        currentElement();
    changeBackground();
        listElNodesWidth = stackedCardsObj.offsetWidth;
        currentElementObj = listElNodesObj[0];
        updateUi();

        //Prepare elements on DOM
        addMargin = elementsMargin * (items -1) + 'px';
        if(stackedOptions === "Top"){
            for(i = items; i < maxElements; i++){
                listElNodesObj[i].classList.add('stackedcards-top', 'stackedcards--animatable', 'stackedcards-origin-top');
            }
            elTrans = elementsMargin * (items - 1);
            stackedCardsObj.style.marginBottom = addMargin;
        }else if(stackedOptions === "Bottom"){
            for(i = items; i < maxElements; i++){
                listElNodesObj[i].classList.add('stackedcards-bottom', 'stackedcards--animatable', 'stackedcards-origin-bottom');
            }
            elTrans = 0;
            stackedCardsObj.style.marginBottom = addMargin;
        }else if (stackedOptions === "None"){
            for(i = items; i < maxElements; i++){
                listElNodesObj[i].classList.add('stackedcards-none', 'stackedcards--animatable');
            }
            elTrans = 0;
        }
        for(i = items; i < maxElements; i++){
            listElNodesObj[i].style.zIndex = 0;
            listElNodesObj[i].style.opacity = 0;
            listElNodesObj[i].style.webkitTransform ='scale(' + (1 - (items * 0.04)) +') translateX(0) translateY(' + elTrans + 'px) translateZ(0)';
            listElNodesObj[i].style.transform ='scale(' + (1 - (items * 0.04)) +') translateX(0) translateY(' + elTrans + 'px) translateZ(0)';
        }
        if(listElNodesObj[currentPosition]){
            listElNodesObj[currentPosition].classList.add('stackedcards-active');
        }
        if(useOverlays){
            leftObj.style.transform = 'translateX(0px) translateY(' + elTrans + 'px) translateZ(0px) rotate(0deg)';
            leftObj.style.webkitTransform = 'translateX(0px) translateY(' + elTrans + 'px) translateZ(0px) rotate(0deg)';
            rightObj.style.transform = 'translateX(0px) translateY(' + elTrans + 'px) translateZ(0px) rotate(0deg)';
            rightObj.style.webkitTransform = 'translateX(0px) translateY(' + elTrans + 'px) translateZ(0px) rotate(0deg)';
            topObj.style.transform = 'translateX(0px) translateY(' + elTrans + 'px) translateZ(0px) rotate(0deg)';
            topObj.style.webkitTransform = 'translateX(0px) translateY(' + elTrans + 'px) translateZ(0px) rotate(0deg)';
        }else{
            leftObj.className = '';
            rightObj.className = '';
            topObj.className = '';
            leftObj.classList.add('stackedcards-overlay-hidden');
            rightObj.classList.add('stackedcards-overlay-hidden');
            topObj.classList.add('stackedcards-overlay-hidden');
        }

        //Remove class init
        setTimeout(function() {
            obj.classList.remove('init');
        }, 150);
        function backToMiddle() {
            removeNoTransition();
            transformUi(0, 0, 1, currentElementObj);
            if(useOverlays){
                transformUi(0, 0, 0, leftObj);
                transformUi(0, 0, 0, rightObj);
                transformUi(0, 0, 0, topObj);
            }
            setZindex(5);
            if(!(currentPosition >= maxElements)){
                //roll back the opacity of second element
                if((currentPosition + 1) < maxElements){
                    listElNodesObj[currentPosition + 1].style.opacity = '.8';
                }
            }
        };

        // Usable functions
        function countElements() {
            maxElements = listElNodesObj.length;
            if(items > maxElements){
                items = maxElements;
            }
        };

        //Keep the active card.
        function currentElement() {
          currentElementObj = listElNodesObj[currentPosition];
        };

        //Change background for each swipe.
        function changeBackground() {
      document.body.classList.add("background-" + currentPosition + "");
        };

        //Change states
        function changeStages() {
      if(currentPosition == maxElements){
        //Event listener created to know when transition ends and changes states
        listElNodesObj[maxElements - 1].addEventListener('transitionend', function(){
          document.body.classList.add("background-7");
          document.querySelector('.stage').classList.add('hidden');
                    refreshObj.classList.add("showcard");
                    rotateTxt.classList.add("showcard");
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        location.reload();
                    }, 3000);
                    listElNodesObj[maxElements - 1].removeEventListener('transitionend', null, false);
                    // document.querySelector('.final-state').classList.remove('hidden');
          // document.querySelector('.final-state').classList.add('active');
        });
      }
        };

        //Functions to swipe left elements on logic external action.
        function onActionLeft() {
            if(!(currentPosition >= maxElements)){
                if(useOverlays) {
                    leftObj.classList.remove('no-transition');
                    topObj.classList.remove('no-transition');
                    leftObj.style.zIndex = '8';
                    transformUi(0, 0, 1, leftObj);
                }
                setTimeout(function() {
                    onSwipeLeft();
                    resetOverlayLeft();
                }, 300);
            }
        };

        //Functions to swipe right elements on logic external action.
        function onActionRight() {
            if(!(currentPosition >= maxElements)){
                if(useOverlays) {
                    rightObj.classList.remove('no-transition');
                    topObj.classList.remove('no-transition');
                    rightObj.style.zIndex = '8';
                    transformUi(0, 0, 1, rightObj);
                }
                setTimeout(function(){
                    onSwipeRight();
                    resetOverlayRight();
                }, 300);
            }
        };

        //Functions to swipe top elements on logic external action.
        function onActionTop() {
            if(!(currentPosition >= maxElements)){
                if(useOverlays) {
                    leftObj.classList.remove('no-transition');
                    rightObj.classList.remove('no-transition');
                    topObj.classList.remove('no-transition');
                    topObj.style.zIndex = '8';
                    transformUi(0, 0, 1, topObj);
                }
                setTimeout(function(){
                    onSwipeTop();
                    resetOverlays();
                }, 300); //wait animations end
            }
        };

        //Swipe active card to left.
        function onSwipeLeft() {
            var hidid = $(".cardform").closest('form').find('.hidden').val();
            // console.log(hidid);
            alert(hidid);
            removeNoTransition();
            transformUi(-1000, 0, 0, currentElementObj);
            if(useOverlays){
                transformUi(-1000, 0, 0, leftObj); // Move leftOverlay
                transformUi(-1000, 0, 0, topObj); // Move topOverlay
                resetOverlayLeft();
            }
            currentPosition = currentPosition + 1;
            updateUi();
            currentElement();
          changeBackground();
          changeStages();
            setActiveHidden();
        };

        //Swipe active card to right.
        function onSwipeRight() {
            removeNoTransition();
            transformUi(1000, 0, 0, currentElementObj);
            if(useOverlays){
                transformUi(1000, 0, 0, rightObj); //Move rightOverlay
                transformUi(1000, 0, 0, topObj); //Move topOverlay
                resetOverlayRight();
            }
            currentPosition = currentPosition + 1;
            updateUi();
            currentElement();
      changeBackground();
      changeStages();
            setActiveHidden();
        };

        //Swipe active card to top.
        function onSwipeTop() {
            removeNoTransition();
            transformUi(0, -1000, 0, currentElementObj);
            if(useOverlays){
                transformUi(0, -1000, 0, leftObj); //Move leftOverlay
                transformUi(0, -1000, 0, rightObj); //Move rightOverlay
                transformUi(0, -1000, 0, topObj); //Move topOverlay
                resetOverlays();
            }
            currentPosition = currentPosition + 1;
            updateUi();
            currentElement();
      changeBackground();
      changeStages();
            setActiveHidden();
        };

        // Remove transitions from all elements to be moved in each swipe movement to improve perfomance of stacked cards.
        function removeNoTransition() {
            if(listElNodesObj[currentPosition]){
                if(useOverlays) {
                    leftObj.classList.remove('no-transition');
                    rightObj.classList.remove('no-transition');
                    topObj.classList.remove('no-transition');
                }
                listElNodesObj[currentPosition].classList.remove('no-transition');
                listElNodesObj[currentPosition].style.zIndex = 6;
            }
        };

        // Move the overlay left to initial position.
        function resetOverlayLeft() {
            if(!(currentPosition >= maxElements)){
                if(useOverlays){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        if(stackedOptions === "Top"){
                            elTrans = elementsMargin * (items - 1);
                        }else if(stackedOptions === "Bottom" || stackedOptions === "None"){
                            elTrans = 0;
                        }
                        if(!isFirstTime){
                            leftObj.classList.add('no-transition');
                            topObj.classList.add('no-transition');
                        }
                        requestAnimationFrame(function(){
                            leftObj.style.transform = "translateX(0) translateY(" + elTrans + "px) translateZ(0)";
                            leftObj.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(0) translateY(" + elTrans + "px) translateZ(0)";
                            leftObj.style.opacity = '0';
                            topObj.style.transform = "translateX(0) translateY(" + elTrans + "px) translateZ(0)";
                            topObj.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(0) translateY(" + elTrans + "px) translateZ(0)";
                            topObj.style.opacity = '0';
                        });
                    },300);
                    isFirstTime = false;
                }
            }
       };

        // Move the overlay right to initial position.
        function resetOverlayRight() {
            if(!(currentPosition >= maxElements)){
                if(useOverlays){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        if(stackedOptions === "Top"){+2
                            elTrans = elementsMargin * (items - 1);
                        }else if(stackedOptions === "Bottom" || stackedOptions === "None"){
                            elTrans = 0;
                        }
                        if(!isFirstTime){
                            rightObj.classList.add('no-transition');
                            topObj.classList.add('no-transition');
                        }
                        requestAnimationFrame(function(){
                            rightObj.style.transform = "translateX(0) translateY(" + elTrans + "px) translateZ(0)";
                            rightObj.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(0) translateY(" + elTrans + "px) translateZ(0)";
                            rightObj.style.opacity = '0';
                            topObj.style.transform = "translateX(0) translateY(" + elTrans + "px) translateZ(0)";
                            topObj.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(0) translateY(" + elTrans + "px) translateZ(0)";
                            topObj.style.opacity = '0';
                        });
                    },300);
                    isFirstTime = false;
                }
            }
       };

        // Move the overlays to initial position.
        function resetOverlays() {
            if(!(currentPosition >= maxElements)){
                if(useOverlays){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        if(stackedOptions === "Top"){
                            elTrans = elementsMargin * (items - 1);
                        }else if(stackedOptions === "Bottom" || stackedOptions === "None"){
                            elTrans = 0;
                        }
                        if(!isFirstTime){
                            leftObj.classList.add('no-transition');
                            rightObj.classList.add('no-transition');
                            topObj.classList.add('no-transition');
                        }
                        requestAnimationFrame(function(){
                            leftObj.style.transform = "translateX(0) translateY(" + elTrans + "px) translateZ(0)";
                            leftObj.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(0) translateY(" + elTrans + "px) translateZ(0)";
                            leftObj.style.opacity = '0';
                            rightObj.style.transform = "translateX(0) translateY(" + elTrans + "px) translateZ(0)";
                            rightObj.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(0) translateY(" + elTrans + "px) translateZ(0)";
                            rightObj.style.opacity = '0';
                            topObj.style.transform = "translateX(0) translateY(" + elTrans + "px) translateZ(0)";
                            topObj.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(0) translateY(" + elTrans + "px) translateZ(0)";
                            topObj.style.opacity = '0';
                        });
                    }, 300);    // wait for animations time
                    isFirstTime = false;
                }
            }
       };

        function setActiveHidden() {
            if(!(currentPosition >= maxElements)){
                listElNodesObj[currentPosition - 1].classList.remove('stackedcards-active');
                listElNodesObj[currentPosition - 1].classList.add('stackedcards-hidden');
                listElNodesObj[currentPosition].classList.add('stackedcards-active');
            }
        };

        //Set the new z-index for specific card.
        function setZindex(zIndex) {
            if(listElNodesObj[currentPosition]){
                listElNodesObj[currentPosition].style.zIndex = zIndex;
            }
        };

    // Remove element from the DOM after swipe. To use this method you need to call this function in onSwipeLeft, onSwipeRight and onSwipeTop and put the method just above the variable 'currentPosition = currentPosition + 1'.
    // On the actions onSwipeLeft, onSwipeRight and onSwipeTop you need to remove the currentPosition variable (currentPosition = currentPosition + 1) and the function setActiveHidden

        function removeElement() {
      currentElementObj.remove();
      if(!(currentPosition >= maxElements)){
                listElNodesObj[currentPosition].classList.add('stackedcards-active');
            }
        };

        //Add translate X and Y to active card for each frame.
        function transformUi(moveX,moveY,opacity,elementObj) {
            requestAnimationFrame(function(){
                var element = elementObj;
                // Function to generate rotate value
                function RotateRegulator(value) {
                   if(value/10 > 15) {
                       return 15;
                   }
                   else if(value/10 < -15) {
                       return -15;
                   }
                   return value/10;
                }
                if(rotate){
                    rotateElement = RotateRegulator(moveX);
                } else {
                    rotateElement = 0;
                }
                if(stackedOptions === "Top"){
                    elTrans = elementsMargin * (items - 1);
                    if(element){
                        element.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(" + moveX + "px) translateY(" + (moveY + elTrans) + "px) translateZ(0) rotate(" + rotateElement + "deg)";
                        element.style.transform = "translateX(" + moveX + "px) translateY(" + (moveY + elTrans) + "px) translateZ(0) rotate(" + rotateElement + "deg)";
                        element.style.opacity = opacity;
                    }
                }else if(stackedOptions === "Bottom" || stackedOptions === "None"){
                    if(element){
                        element.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(" + moveX + "px) translateY(" + (moveY) + "px) translateZ(0) rotate(" + rotateElement + "deg)";
                        element.style.transform = "translateX(" + moveX + "px) translateY(" + (moveY) + "px) translateZ(0) rotate(" + rotateElement + "deg)";
                        element.style.opacity = opacity;
                    }
                }
            });
        };

        //Action to update all elements on the DOM for each stacked card.
        function updateUi() {
            requestAnimationFrame(function(){
                elTrans = 0;
                var elZindex = 5;
                var elScale = 1;
                var elOpac = 1;
                var elTransTop = items;
                var elTransInc = elementsMargin;
                for(i = currentPosition; i < (currentPosition + items); i++){
                    if(listElNodesObj[i]){
                        if(stackedOptions === "Top"){
                            listElNodesObj[i].classList.add('stackedcards-top', 'stackedcards--animatable', 'stackedcards-origin-top');
                            if(useOverlays){
                                leftObj.classList.add('stackedcards-origin-top');
                                rightObj.classList.add('stackedcards-origin-top');
                                topObj.classList.add('stackedcards-origin-top');
                            }
                            elTrans = elTransInc * elTransTop;
                            elTransTop--;
                        }else if(stackedOptions === "Bottom"){
                            listElNodesObj[i].classList.add('stackedcards-bottom', 'stackedcards--animatable', 'stackedcards-origin-bottom');
                            if(useOverlays){
                                leftObj.classList.add('stackedcards-origin-bottom');
                                rightObj.classList.add('stackedcards-origin-bottom');
                                topObj.classList.add('stackedcards-origin-bottom');
                            }
                            elTrans = elTrans + elTransInc;
                        }else if (stackedOptions === "None"){
                            listElNodesObj[i].classList.add('stackedcards-none', 'stackedcards--animatable');
                            elTrans = elTrans + elTransInc;
                        }
                        listElNodesObj[i].style.transform ='scale(' + elScale + ') translateX(0) translateY(' + (elTrans - elTransInc) + 'px) translateZ(0)';
                        listElNodesObj[i].style.webkitTransform ='scale(' + elScale + ') translateX(0) translateY(' + (elTrans - elTransInc) + 'px) translateZ(0)';
                        listElNodesObj[i].style.opacity = elOpac;
                        listElNodesObj[i].style.zIndex = elZindex;
                        elScale = elScale - 0.04;
                        elOpac = elOpac - (1 / items);
                        elZindex--;
                    }
                }
            });
        };

        //Touch events block
        var element = obj;
        var startTime;
        var startX;
        var startY;
        var translateX;
        var translateY;
        var currentX;
        var currentY;
        var touchingElement = false;
        var timeTaken;
        var topOpacity;
        var rightOpacity;
        var leftOpacity;

        function setOverlayOpacity() {
            topOpacity = (((translateY + (elementHeight) / 2) / 100) * -1);
            rightOpacity = translateX / 100;
            leftOpacity = ((translateX / 100) * -1);
            if(topOpacity > 1) {
                topOpacity = 1;
            }
            if(rightOpacity > 1) {
                rightOpacity = 1;
            }
            if(leftOpacity > 1) {
                leftOpacity = 1;
            }
        }

        function gestureStart(evt) {
            startTime = new Date().getTime();
            startX = evt.changedTouches[0].clientX;
            startY = evt.changedTouches[0].clientY;
            currentX = startX;
            currentY = startY;
            setOverlayOpacity();
            touchingElement = true;
            if(!(currentPosition >= maxElements)){
                if(listElNodesObj[currentPosition]){
                    listElNodesObj[currentPosition].classList.add('no-transition');
                    setZindex(6);
                    if(useOverlays){
                        leftObj.classList.add('no-transition');
                        rightObj.classList.add('no-transition');
                        topObj.classList.add('no-transition');
                    }
                    if((currentPosition + 1) < maxElements){
                        listElNodesObj[currentPosition + 1].style.opacity = '1';
                    }
                    elementHeight = listElNodesObj[currentPosition].offsetHeight / 3;
                }
            }
        };

        function gestureMove(evt) {
            currentX = evt.changedTouches[0].pageX;
            currentY = evt.changedTouches[0].pageY;
            translateX = currentX - startX;
            translateY = currentY - startY;
            setOverlayOpacity();
            if(!(currentPosition >= maxElements)){
                evt.preventDefault();
                transformUi(translateX, translateY, 1, currentElementObj);
                if(useOverlays){
                    transformUi(translateX, translateY, topOpacity, topObj);
                    if(translateX < 0){
                        transformUi(translateX, translateY, leftOpacity, leftObj);
                        transformUi(0, 0, 0, rightObj);
                    }else if(translateX > 0){
                        transformUi(translateX, translateY, rightOpacity, rightObj);
                        transformUi(0, 0, 0, leftObj);
                    }
                    if(useOverlays){
                        leftObj.style.zIndex = 8;
                        rightObj.style.zIndex = 8;
                        topObj.style.zIndex = 7;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        function gestureEnd(evt){
            if(!touchingElement){
                return;
            }
            translateX = currentX - startX;
            translateY = currentY - startY;
            timeTaken = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
            touchingElement = false;
            if(!(currentPosition >= maxElements)){
                if(translateY < (elementHeight * -1) && translateX > ((listElNodesWidth / 2) * -1) && translateX < (listElNodesWidth / 2)){  //is Top?
                    if(translateY < (elementHeight * -1) || (Math.abs(translateY) / timeTaken > velocity)){ // Did It Move To Top?
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }else{
                        backToMiddle();
                    }
                }else{
                    if(translateX < 0){
                        if(translateX < ((listElNodesWidth / 2) * -1) || (Math.abs(translateX) / timeTaken > velocity)){ // Did It Move To Left?
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }else{
                            backToMiddle();
                        }
                    }else if(translateX > 0){
                        if(translateX > (listElNodesWidth / 2) && (Math.abs(translateX) / timeTaken > velocity)){ // Did It Move To Right?
                            onSwipeRight();
                        }else{
                            backToMiddle();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        element.addEventListener('touchstart', gestureStart, false);
        element.addEventListener('touchmove', gestureMove, false);
        element.addEventListener('touchend', gestureEnd, false);
        //Add listeners to call global action for swipe cards
        var buttonLeft = document.querySelector('.left-action');
        var buttonTop = document.querySelector('.top-action');
        var buttonRight = document.querySelector('.right-action');
        buttonLeft.addEventListener('click', onActionLeft, false);
        buttonTop.addEventListener('click', onActionTop, false);
        buttonRight.addEventListener('click', onActionRight, false);
    }
    stackedCards();
});
```

Comment: `.val()` always returns only one value, from the first matched element.

Comment: @Pointy so what else should be used here? I don't think that is the issue here.

Comment: If you want an array of all the values, use `.map()`

Comment: `.map()` in place of `.val()` ? Doesn't work....

Comment: Also this is not a PHP issue. Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve] with ONLY HTML, CSS and JavaScript/jQuery

Comment: Not instead, in addition. You use `.val()` in the callback function.

Comment: What do you actually want to see in the alert? All the rows, the current row, something else?

Comment: @Barmar a working example would be appreciated. Its confusing me.

Comment: A working example of what? You haven't explained what it's supposed to do instead.

Comment: For each card swipe when the function gets fired I want it to fetch the value of the hidden input field of each card which is of course different for each cards.

Comment: `$(".cardform").closest('form')` doesn't select anything. `.cardform` is the form, `.closest()` looks for a container, not the element of itself.

Comment: How is `onSwipeLeft()` being called? How is it supposed to know which card's value to show?

Comment: Its a whole library. I only posted the particular function which is being used here. Should I post the whole library too? Contains 582 lines of code.

Comment: On each swap you are reading the value of first  .cardform not the .cardform in the card that was swapped. You need to find out what is onSwapLeft is attached to, then use 'this' to identify the card you are in and then find the .cardform of THAT card.

Comment: @NawedKhan I agree with your view. However, I have weak hands on Javascript and by looking at your comment I can say that you give me a solution as to how I can achieve this if you happen to take a look at my library. I have hence, attached the library. Please take a look and give an answer as to where I need to use `this` here. The function `onSwipeLeft` is being called at 2 locations at line 155 and 555. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the library it can be seen that `currentElementObj` is where currently active card is stored. We can then find the form and hidden field from this object like this:

```
 //Swipe active card to left.
        function onSwipeLeft() {
            var hidid = $(currentElementObj).find('form .hidden').val();
            // console.log(hidid);
            alert(hidid);
            removeNoTransition();
            transformUi(-1000, 0, 0, currentElementObj);
            if(useOverlays){
                transformUi(-1000, 0, 0, leftObj); // Move leftOverlay
                transformUi(-1000, 0, 0, topObj); // Move topOverlay
                resetOverlayLeft();
            }
            currentPosition = currentPosition + 1;
            updateUi();
            currentElement();
          changeBackground();
          changeStages();
            setActiveHidden();
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the jQuery function `.val()` just returns the value of the first element you selected.

you have to `$.each()` through all hidden elements in your forms and put the value into an array, then you can output them in your `alert()`

code example

```
var array = [];
$('.cardform').find('.hidden').each(function(index, element) {
    array[index] = $(element).val();
})
alert(array);
```

Comment: This returns a comma separated value of both at once on "every" swipe. This is not what I am looking for. I am actually looking for is that every swipe returns the attached ID of its own card.